# How to persist a cookie?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cookies

I am creating a cookie in a jsp script, which is located at:

```
www.myproject.com/login/index.jsp
```

if I restart the browser and navigate there, all works well, I can see the cookie persist. If I navigate to:

```
www.myproject.com
```

I am not seeing the cookie. Do I need to set something in the cookie path or domain to make the cookie visible to the entire [myproject.com] domain (I just want to access the cookie from whatever sub path the user may be on). I am creating the cookie like:

```
Cookie c = new Cookie("thisisatest", "foo");
c.setMaxAge(60 * 24 * 3600);
response.addCookie(c);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You indeed need to set the cookie path. This defaults to the current path. You can do that by [`Cookie#setPath()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setPath%28java.lang.String%29).

```
Cookie c = new Cookie("thisisatest", "foo");
c.setMaxAge(60 * 24 * 3600);
c.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, cookies are returned only to the host that saved them.

try to set a domain to a cookie

Check Out:  http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch07_04.htm

Comment: The (sub)domain is not the problem here.

Comment: Set cookie header's path attribute to /. "/" means applicable to all site